# How do I get a recursive function call to save its out put from a tkinter GUI user input?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, recursion

I am relatively new to Python and new to GUI development. Below is Python code for a draft GUI that I am developing for tracking the review progress of a document. Eventually the GUI will provide status on document review progress based on user input but I am not there yet. At this stage I am just trying to get the base functions debugged. The current sticking point involves an issue where a recursive function call (`compare_stages()`) fails to either save its output or run at all. Specifically, when I test run the last function (`enter_stage_completed()`) edge case that triggers the recursive call in `compare_stages()`, a `NoneType` error occurs. The edge case of user input selections is:

1. Select review stage (click on "client_review").
2. Select reviewer name (click on "Sue", text box appears prompting user to choose another review stage because the reviewer (Sue) has already reviewed the selected stage).
3. Select review stage (click on "reg_review").
4. Select reviewer name (click on "Sue").

Step 4 is where the `NoneType` error occurs because the output of `compare_stages()` does not occur and thus there is no object for the variable `stage[0]` needed in `enter_stage_completed()`. I have no idea why this is happening. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


doc_list = ["doc_A","doc_B","doc_C","doc_D"]
review_stages = ["internal_review","client_review","reg_review"]
reviewer_list = ["Sue","Joe","Don","Billy"]
doc_reviews_completed = ["doc_B"]
review_stages_completed = ["internal_review"]
Sue_stages_complete = ["client_review"]
Joe_stages_complete = []
Don_stages_complete = []
Billy_stages_complete = []


def select_doc():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("715x250")
        
    def save_selected(choice):
        choice = menu.get()
        return choice    
      
    menu = StringVar()
    menu.set("Select Document")
    drop = OptionMenu(
        win,
        menu,
        *doc_list,
        command=save_selected
        )
    drop.pack()
    win.mainloop()
    
    return save_selected(menu)


def prnt_doc_complete():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("250x170")
    T = Text(win, height = 5, width = 40)
    l = Label(win, text = "Oops!")
    l.config(font =("Courier", 14))
    message = """Document review complete. Please choose again."""
    l.pack()
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, message)
    return win.mainloop()


def compare_doc_lists():
    a = select_doc()
    if a in doc_reviews_completed:
        prnt_doc_complete()
        compare_doc_lists()
    else:
        return a
    
#compare_doc_lists()    

def select_reviewer():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("715x250")
    
    def save_selected(choice):
        choice = menu.get()
        return choice
    
    menu = StringVar()
    menu.set("Select reviewer name.")
    drop = OptionMenu(
        win,
        menu,
        *reviewer_list,
        command=save_selected
        )
    drop.pack()
    win.mainloop()
    
    return save_selected(menu)

# select_reviewer()

def select_stage():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("715x250")
    
    def save_selected(choice):
        choice = menu.get()
        return choice
    
    menu = StringVar()
    menu.set("Select review stage.")
    drop = OptionMenu(
        win,
        menu,
        *review_stages,
        command=save_selected
        )
    drop.pack()
    win.mainloop()
    
    return save_selected(menu)

# select_stage()

def prnt_stage_complete():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("250x170")
    T = Text(win, height = 5, width = 40)
    l = Label(win, text = "Oops!")
    l.config(font =("Courier", 14))
    message = """The selected stage is complete for this document. Please choose again."""
    l.pack()
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, message)
    return win.mainloop()

def prnt_stage_complete_reviewer():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("250x170")
    T = Text(win, height = 5, width = 40)
    l = Label(win, text = "Oops!")
    l.config(font =("Courier", 14))
    message = """You have already completed this review stage. Please choose again."""
    l.pack()
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, message)
    return win.mainloop()

def compare_stages():
    stage_choice = select_stage()
    reviewer = select_reviewer()
    
    if reviewer == "Sue":
        stage_list = Sue_stages_complete
    if reviewer == "Joe":
        stage_list = Joe_stages_complete
    if reviewer == "Don":
        stage_list = Don_stages_complete
    if reviewer == "Billy":
        stage_list = Billy_stages_complete

    if stage_choice in review_stages_completed:
        prnt_stage_complete()
        compare_stages()
    elif stage_choice in stage_list:
        prnt_stage_complete_reviewer()
        compare_stages()
    else:
        return stage_choice, reviewer
    
def prnt_all_stage_complete():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("250x170")
    T = Text(win, height = 5, width = 40)
    l = Label(win, text = "Oops!")
    l.config(font =("Courier", 14))
    message = """All reviews already completed. You are done!"""
    l.pack()
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, message)
    return win.mainloop()
    
def enter_stage_completed():
    """
    Function for user to select the current stage that they are completing.

    Returns
    -------
    Updates to docs_complete, stages_complete, and/or reviewer_stages complete lists. User indicates that the stage is complete and the stage is added to their stages_completed list. For tracking, a MySQL database will be populated (allows nulls).

    """
    stage = compare_stages()
       
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("100x100")
    
    def save_selected():
        text=f"{stage[0]}"
        return text
       
    l = Label(win, text="Click to confirm that you completed reviewing the previously selected review stage.")
    l.pack()   
    btn = Button(
        master = win,
        text=f"{stage[0]}",
        command=save_selected
        )
    
    #txt = btn.text
    btn.pack()
    
    win.mainloop()
    
    return save_selected()
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should not create more than once instance of `Tk`. I can cause some problems if you're not aware of exactly what it means to create more than one instance. Most of the time you should use instances of `Toplevel` for the second and subsequent windows. Whether this is the root cause of the problem or not, I don't know, but it might be a contributing factor.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. In that case, I should only use one window (win)  that contains all of the widgets that I have created?

Comment: Usually a tkinter opens one window, and that window says alive for the life of the program. You can easily replace the contents of a window with destroying and recreating it.